# Issues rendering data fetched with useEffect in a custom hook

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I am a beginner in React and using React hooks. I have a function component that needs to show some info on the page. I receive the and return the `jobs` array correctly and I can iterate in it with `map` and show its info successfully, but want to receive another array too:`location`. this array is based on the `jobs` array: I need to receive `jobs` first, then get its location id and then receive info and put it into my location array to be used in my info page later. the problem is, that when I add the location array I receive multiple errors such as `res.json is not a function` and so on. here's my code:

```
function useJobs () {
  const [jobs, setJobs] = React.useState([])
  const [locations, setLocations] = React.useState([])
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/api/jobs/list-jobs', { headers: headers })
      .then(r => r.json())
      .then(setJobs)
  }, [])
  React.useEffect(() => {
    jobs.map(job => (
      axios.get(`/api/jobs/view-location/${job.location}/`, { headers: headers })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(setLocations)
    ))
  }, [jobs], [])

  return (jobs, locations)
}

export default function Jobs () {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const jobs = useJobs()
  const locations = useJobs()
  return (
    <>
   {jobs.map(job => (

          <>
            <div className={classes.root} key={job.id}>
......
<Row>
      <Col style={{ color: 'black' }}>Title:{job.title} </Col>
      <Col>Company Name:{job.company_name} </Col>
      <Col style={{ color: 'black' }}>Internal Code:{job.internal_code} </Col>
 </Row>

{locations.map(location => (
 <Col key={location.id} style={{ color: 'black' }}>Location:{location.country}</Col>))
}
```

as you see, before I added the `location` part, my `job` info was showing correctly. but when I want to show the location info based on the info that `job.location` GET request provided, I receive these errors. what part am I doing wrong? what is the correct way to implement this?

Comment: You should be aware of the asynchronous nature of javascript here.
You call   :
const jobs = useJobs()
const locations = useJobs()

and then you try to display the results. Right?

Javascript code is not blocking, and that means that code execution continues after the 2 functions calls. Your code will try to display the server response before the response is ready. You have to use callbacks or promises to grab the response from the server.

Comment: Side note: It's not the problem, but something else I noticed in your code: it's falling prey to the footgun in the `fetch` API: `fetch` only rejects on *network* error, not HTTP error; you have to check for that separately (usually by checking `response.ok`). Details [on my anemic little blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html).

Answer (score 2):

- An axios request response doens't need to be run through `res.json()`. It is required for a fetch request. Also `axios` response has multiple information and the data is provided with `resp.data`
- Also useEffect dependency is just one argument instead you are passing two

```
      React.useEffect(() => {
        axios('/api/jobs/list-jobs', { headers: headers })
          .then(res => setJobs(res.data))
      }, [])
      React.useEffect(() => {
        jobs.map(job => (
          axios.get(`/api/jobs/view-location/${job.location}/`, { headers: headers })
            .then(res => setLocations(prev => ({...prev, [job.id]: res.data})))

        ))
      }, [jobs])
```

- Another thing to note here is that `useJobs` hook returns both locations and jobs so you don't need to execute it twice and not that you need to return the result from useJobs as an object i.e have

```
    return { jobs, locations }
```

instead of

```
    return ( jobs, locations )
```

- Also while updating locations you are overriding the locations, please use object for locations

Full code:

```
function useJobs () {

  const [jobs, setJobs] = React.useState([])
  const [locations, setLocations] = React.useState({})
  React.useEffect(() => {
    axios('/api/jobs/list-jobs', { headers: headers })
      .then(res => setJobs(res.data))
  }, [])
  React.useEffect(() => {
    for (const job of jobs) {
      axios(`/api/jobs/view-location/${job.location}/`, { headers: headers })
        .then((data) => {
           setLocations(prev => ({...prev, [job.id]: res.data}))
        })
    }
  }, [jobs])

  return [jobs, locations]
}


export default function Jobs () {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const { jobs,locations} = useJobs();
  return (
    <>
      {jobs.map(job => (

          <>
            <div className={classes.root} key={job.id}>
......

        <Row>
              <Col style={{ color: 'black' }}>Title:{job.title} </Col>
              <Col>Company Name:{job.company_name} </Col>
              <Col style={{ color: 'black' }}>Internal Code:{job.internal_code} </Col>

         </Row>


        {locations[job.id].map(location => (
            <Col key={location.id} style={{ color: 'black' 
         }}>Location:{location.country}</Col>))
         }
```

Comment: Please check my post and let me know if it doens't work for you

Answer (score 1):

This line does not return `jobs` and `locations`:

```
return (jobs, locations)
```

Instead, it evaluates `jobs`, throws away that result, evaluates `locations`, and returns that value.

If you meant to return an array containing `jobs` and `locations`, you can either return an array containing them as entries:

```
return [jobs, locations];
```

and use it like this, rather than making two calls to `useJobs`:

```
const [jobs, locations] = useJobs();
```

or return an object containing them as properties:

```
return {jobs, locations};
```

and use it like this, again rather than making two calls to `useJobs`:

```
const {jobs, locations} = useJobs();
```

---

There are a couple of other things that jump out:

1. As I mentioned in a comment, your code is falling prey to the footgun in the `fetch` API: `fetch` only rejects on *network* error, not HTTP error; you have to check for that separately (usually by checking `response.ok`). Details [on my anemic little blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html).
2. [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) only accepts up to two arguments, not three. You're using three here:

   ```
   React.useEffect(() => {
     jobs.map(job => (
       axios.get(`/api/jobs/view-location/${job.location}/`, { headers: headers })
         .then(res => res.json())
         .then(setLocations)
     ))
   }, [jobs], [])
   // −−−−−−^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− remove
   ```
3. It seems odd to use `fetch` in one place but `axios` in another. I suggest standardizing on one or the other. Unless you have a good reason for using `axios`, I'd probably just use a wrapper on `fetch` that checks for HTTP errors and rejects.
4. I don't use `axios`, but [Shubham Khatri points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61653447/157247) issues with the usage of it in your code.
5. You're using `map` as a simple iterator for an array. That's never appropriate, `map` is for creating a **new** array from the results of the `map` callback. If you're not using the return value from `map`, use `forEach` (or `for-of`) instead.
6. You're doing an ajax call per job in a loop, but then storing the results in `locations`. That means the results from each call in the loop overwrite any previous results. Presumably you meant to do something with *all* of the results.

Taking that all together:

```
// A reusable JSON fetch wrapper that handles HTTP errors
function fetchJSON(...args) {
    return fetch('/api/jobs/list-jobs', { headers: headers })
      .then(r => {
          if (!r.ok) {
              throw new Error("HTTP error " + r.status)
          }
          return r.json()
      });
}

function useJobs () {
  const [jobs, setJobs] = React.useState([])
  const [locations, setLocations] = React.useState([])
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchJSON('/api/jobs/list-jobs', { headers: headers })
      .then(setJobs)
  }, [])
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // *** Don't use `map` as a simple iteration construct
    for (const job of jobs) {
      fetchJSON(`/api/jobs/view-location/${job.location}/`, { headers: headers })
        .then(setLocations) // *** Need to handle #6 here
    }
  }, [jobs]) // *** No additional array here

  return [jobs, locations]
}

export default function Jobs () {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const [jobs, locations] = useJobs() // *** Use jobs and locations here
  return (
    <>
   {jobs.map(job => (
          <>
            <div className={classes.root} key={job.id}>
            ......
            <Row>
                  <Col style={{ color: 'black' }}>Title:{job.title} </Col>
                  <Col>Company Name:{job.company_name} </Col>
                  <Col style={{ color: 'black' }}>Internal Code:{job.internal_code} </Col>
             </Row>

            {locations.map(location => (
             <Col key={location.id} style={{ color: 'black' }}>Location:{location.country}</Col>))
            }
```

...but that doesn't handle #6.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but now instead of writing the actual location in front of the ```Location:``` n my form, it repeats the text ```Location:`` 3 times in my form with nothing in front of it (I have 3 job objects)

Comment: Its like location.country isn't even defined

Comment: @Dorian - Did you deal with issue #6 above?

Comment: I know that's the issue, but if the useEffect only accepts 2 parameters then how can I save my info in an array like I did with Jobs? I am lost on number 6

Comment: @Dorian - It's hard to help because we don't know what you're trying to do with locations. I think this question is at risk of being too broad. Your best bet is to implement as much of the above as you can, and try to figure out what to do with locations, and if you get stuck, post a new question with a [mcve] of what you've done and an explanation of how you'd like `locations` to work. Then we can focus on that one issue.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers you have also have a problem calling `setLocations`.
Because you call it from inside the map function, you are calling it once for every job.

```
jobs.map(job => (
  axios.get(`/api/jobs/view-location/${job.location}/`, { headers: headers })
    .then(setLocations)
))
```

You are effectively saying:

```
setLocations('London');
setLocations('Paris');
```

It is clear that if you call this twice you loose London, and only persist the final location.

Instead you meant to store all the locations in an array, so wait for all the promises to finish then store them all together.

```
Promise.all(
  jobs.map(job => (
    axios.get(`/api/jobs/view-location/${job.location}/`, { headers: headers })
        .then(response => response.data)
  ))
)
.then(allLocations => setLocations(allLocations))
```